# View Model that contains a List that contains a String List not returning on submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, razor

Working with MVC I have a FormModel:

```
public class FormModel
{  
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<CustomList> CustomList { get; set; }

    public FormModel(){}
}
```

The FormModel class consists of a list of the class CustomList:

```
public class CustomList
{
    public int CustomListId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<String> StringList{ get; set; }

public CustomerList(){}
}
```

which contains a list of Strings.  What I want to achieve is setting up a form that allows the user to edit each of the values in StringList.  To do so I set up my view:

```
@model CMS.Models.FormModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using(Html.BeginForm("DoStuff", "Create", Model))
{
    <div>
        <p>Description: @(Html.EditorFor(e => e.Description))</p>

        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.CustomList.Count; i++)
        {
            @Html.LabelFor(l => l.CustomList[i].Description)
            @Html.HiddenFor(h => h.CustomList[i].CustomListId)
            for (int a = 0; a < Model.CustomList[i].StringList.Count; a++)
            {
                @Html.EditorFor(e => e.CustomList[i].StringList[a])                                        
            }
        }
        <input type="submit" />
    <div>
}
```

On submit the Description in FormModel is returned to the controller but CustomList is returned back Empty.  I've checked a few of links from Joe Stevens but seems i'm missing something.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("DoStuff", "Create", Model))
```

Try:

```
 @using(Html.BeginForm("DoStuff", "Create", FormMethod.Post))
```

Hope this works for you!

@Mystere Man I don't think that instantiating the lists in the constructor was the issue.  I have never heard of or experienced that being an issue with model binding, although that is always a good practice with lists anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate an empty list in the constructor of both your models.  The default model binder does not create the empty Lists for you.  Since there is no list object, it won't bind the values.

It looks correct otherwise.

Comment: Sorry that's all set up before getting passed to the view.  The view itself is getting data passed for the CustomList and StringList

Comment: @Hennish - That's irrelevant.  When you post back to the controller, a new copy of the model is created by the model binder, so the lists are null (not empty).  It doesn't matter what you've done before passing to the view.  After postback, the model is completely reset to default state.  That's why you have to instantiate the empty lists in the constructor of the model.

Comment: Not sure if i'm not fully understanding but when debugging I check the value of the returned model and the CustomList list is set as count of 0 not null. When I instantiate the list in each class the result is the same.

Comment: @Hennish - just instantiate the lists in the constructor.  And you will see that it works.  If you refuse to do that, then why do you bother asking for help if you won't accept it?